# aws-sdk javascript dynamodb getItem with optional range key

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Folks,
  I have a table with hash and range keys setup which I am trying to query.

According to aws-sdk documentation, both rangekey and hashkeys need to be specified.  What is the proper query to not specify the optional rangekey?

I've tried the following with no avail...

```
    var params = {
        TableName: TABLE_NAME,
        AttributesToGet: ['dogs'],
        Key : {
            dogs : {
                S : dogs
            },
            status: {
                NULL: true
            }
        }
    };
```

or

```
    var params = {
        TableName: TABLE_NAME,
        AttributesToGet: ['dogs'],
        Key : {
            dogs : {
                S : 'dogs'
            },
            status: {
                S: ''
            }
        }
    };
```

Ofcourse if I specify the known rangekey, query runs fine.  Wondering how to build a query to return all hashkeys with a blank rangekey :)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing your table is hashKey -> dogs and rangeKey -> status? First, the way to query without a range key is to just not put it in the key conditions. Second, _if_ your table is designed like that, you should be very careful with your table design because "status" based primary keys that are not sparse.

Comment: I didn't really finish my thought there - "status" based primary keys that are not sparse can lead to a lot of other issues down the road - see the **Choosing a Hash Key** section of the [Guidelines for Working with Tables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html) documentation.